# Careers penalized me 5 Points and refuses to tell me why

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The feature nav box says 205/210 points. But the point summary at the bottom shows 210/210. Xbox Live has taught me that every point counts. That means that C.SO is cheating me of my completeness goals! >=-/

But seriously. Any idea what's causing the discrepancy? Very strange to see two different values on the same page. Especially after my points (as listed next to "edit profile") changed from 190 to 205 immediately after making the modification to get the last of the 20 points.

My careers id is 10700.

[image: Annotated Careers Point List Screen]

(Obligatory: 5 Points from Griffindor house!)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently when you add or remove SO questions, no recalc happens, which is certainly a bug.  I fixed your score by forcing a recalc, which you can do by editing anything else that is part of the completeness score.  Thanks for the report, I'll have this fixed shortly.

Comment: This bug still isn't fixed.

Comment: @Sicco It has probably popped back up; I'll look into your case.